# Failed to move file from tmp_dir to server_dir

Tags: php

```
<?php
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES))
    //$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));

        $fileName = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]; 
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];

        $pathAndName = "uploads/".$fileName;
        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);

    if ($moveResult == true) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
        require_once '/home/jaydeepkanada/public_html/phpMailer/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom('accounts@newedgesecurity.in', 'Mail From Website');
        $mail->addAddress('jaydeepkanada@gmail.com', 'Jaydeep Kanada');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
        $mail->msgHTML("My message body");

        $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));
        if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    $msg = "Message sent!";
                }

        }else{
            die("File type not supported. Only PDF or DOC.");
        }  
    } else {
        $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>PHPMailer Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (empty($msg)) { ?>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"> Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Send File">
    </form>
<?php } else {
    echo $msg;
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using PHP mailer for sending mail with attachments and in this code path is correct but it always showing Failed to move path.

Comment: Have you set uploads directory permissions to `777`

Comment: The software that handles the request to process the script above (likely apache, www-data or something to that affect), needs to be the owner of the directory where the files will be stored. Otherwise, you will need to ensure the `group` that belongs to the `user` that is handling the above script (apache, www-data, etc...) has the same group as the user that owns the folder (upload) where the data will be stored, and can both read **and** write (umask: 06**6**4) where the second **6** represents the `rw+` flag for the group.

Comment: You are not checking `$_FILES["userfile"]['error']` to see if the upload was actually completed successfully?

Comment: uploads directory permissions is already set to 777 @madforstrength  and pls gys dont give -ve..php ia just fresh for me..

Comment: @RiggsFolly  can u pls tel me how to chek..

Comment: please check your error log, it will show you exact error

Comment: Surely [here is the PHP manual pages for File Upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and here are the [error codes explianing](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: hay @RiggsFolly i tried $_FILES["userfile"]['error'] and result is 0 i.e UPLOAD_ERR_OK
Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
but file is still not uploaded....

Comment: Did you find anything in the error log?

Comment: no...nothing in error log...if u have a code to move on server direc then pls pest it.....

Comment: hay friends i solved it....i just replace the "(double quote) with '(single quote) for assigning path in $pathAndName..
thnx @RiggsFolly for help...

Answer (score 0):

Use the right convertion on file size MAX_FILE_SIZE value, something like 10485760

The problem is the value inside the `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">` tag being in bytes your uploaded file maybe bigger than 97kbytes (100000 bytes => 97.66 kbytes) so causing the system to give an error (if you look at $_FILES["userfile"]['error'] or $_FILES["userfile"]['error'][0] content, you will see that is giving you error 2 that means "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form".